# How do I remove elements from multiple Lists that are properties of a generic object using reflection?

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I have a generic object that could have mulitple Lists as properties.

How do I remove elements from those lists generically using reflection?

Let's say I have objects that are like below

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public List<long> listA
    public List<string> listB
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public List<int> listC
    public List<decimal> listD
}
```

How would I go about adding and removing elements from those lists generically?

Here's what I thought of, but it's wrong:

```
private bool PropertyIsGenericList(PropertyInfo property)
        {
            return property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType);
        }

private void RemoveElementsFromPropertyThatAreLists(object dto)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in dto.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (dto != null && property != null && PropertyIsGenericList(property))
                {
                    RemoveElementsFromList(property, globalIndex); // Don't know what to pass to this
                }

            }
        }

protected void RemoveElementsFromList<ListType>(List<ListType>? columns, int? startingIndex = null)
        {
            startingIndex = startingIndex != null ? startingIndex.Value : globalIndex;
            if (columns != null)
            {
                for (int columnIndex = columns.Count - 1; startingIndex <= columnIndex; columnIndex--)
                {
                    columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You would need to `.MakeGenericMethod` before you can invoke if via reflection. But the larger question is "Why?". What problem are you actually trying to solve, and can you find a way to solve it without reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Lists of any type supports interface `IList`, you can do your manupulations via that interface:

```
private void RemoveElementsFromPropertyThatAreLists(object dto)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in dto.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (dto != null && PropertyIsGenericList(property))
        {
            var list = (IList)property.GetValue(dto);
            RemoveElementsFromList(property, globalIndex); 
        }

    }
}

protected void RemoveElementsFromList(IList columns, int? startingIndex = null)
{
    startingIndex = startingIndex != null ? startingIndex.Value : globalIndex;
    if (columns != null)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = columns.Count - 1; startingIndex <= columnIndex; columnIndex--)
        {
            columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```